# Some trouble with ComboBox in Ext.net

Tags: ext.net

I have a Page which a FormPanel(there's a ComboBox in it) and a TreePanel(has a default root node) in it and open ViewState.

I set a value to ComboBox in GET.

When i GET the page the TreePanel's Store send a POST request(store read) before FormPane rendered in client,in this POST request the fromdata has no info about FormPane.

in the POST request recover the ComboBox.Value from ViewState,but in ComboBoxBase.LoadPostData() Ext.Net get value from formdata and cover ComboBox.Value without precondition

it's ComboBoxBase.LoadPostData() code

```
protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   {
       this.HasLoadPostData = true;

       string text = postCollection[this.UniqueName];
       string state = postCollection[this.ValueHiddenName.IsNotEmpty() ? this.ValueHiddenName : ("_" + this.UniqueName + "_state")];

       this.SuspendScripting();
       this.RawValue = text;
       this.Value = text;
       this.ResumeScripting();

       if (state == null && text == null)
       {
           return false;
       }

       if (!this.EmptyText.Equals(text) && text.IsNotEmpty())
       {
           List<ListItem> items = null;
           if (this.SimpleSubmit)
           {
               var array = state.Split(new char[] { ',' });
               items = new List<ListItem>(array.Length);
               foreach (var item in array)
               {
                   items.Add(new ListItem(item));
               }                    
           }
           else if(state.IsNotEmpty())
           {
               items = ComboBoxBase.ParseSelectedItems(state);
           }

           bool fireEvent = false;

           if (items == null)
           {
               items = new List<ListItem> 
               { 
                   new ListItem(text)
               };                    

               /*fireEvent = this.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
               this.SelectedItems.Clear();
               return fireEvent;
               */
           }

           foreach (var item in items)
           {
               if (!this.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
               {
                   fireEvent = true;
                   break;
               }
           }

           this.SelectedItems.Clear();
           this.SelectedItems.AddRange(items);

           return fireEvent;
       }
       else
       {
           if (this.EmptyText.Equals(text) && this.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
           {
               this.SelectedItems.Clear();

               return true;
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
```

Look at Line 5 to 11,why not change like this

```
string text = postCollection[this.UniqueName];
        string state = postCollection[this.ValueHiddenName.IsNotEmpty() ? this.ValueHiddenName : ("_" + this.UniqueName + "_state")];

       this.SuspendScripting();
       this.RawValue = text;
       this.ResumeScripting();

       if (state == null && text == null)
       {
           return false;
       }

       this.SuspendScripting();
       this.Value = text;
       this.ResumeScripting();
```

Sample for this question

page file

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" DisableViewState="false"
        AjaxViewStateMode="Enabled"  ViewStateMode="Enabled"/>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ext:Viewport runat="server" ID="VP">
    </ext:Viewport>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs file

```
public partial class WebFormTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        FP = new FormPanel();
        FP.ID = "FP";
        FP.Title = "FP";
        FP.Region = Region.Center;

        TF = new TextField();
        TF.ID = "TF";
        TF.FieldLabel = "TF";

        CB = new ComboBox();
        CB.ID = "CB";
        CB.FieldLabel = "CB";
        CB.Items.Clear();
        CB.Items.Add(new ListItem("one", "1"));
        CB.Items.Add(new ListItem("two", "2"));

        Button test = new Button() { ID = "testbtn", Text = "test" };
        test.Listeners.Click.Handler = "App.Store2.load()";
        FP.TopBar.Add(new Toolbar() { Items = { test } });

        FP.Items.Add(TF);
        FP.Items.Add(CB);

        GP = new GridPanel();
        GP.ID = "GP";
        GP.Title = "GP";
        GP.Region = Region.East;

        GP.Listeners.BeforeRender.Handler = "App.Store1.reload()";

        BTN = new Button();
        BTN.ID = "BTN";
        BTN.Text = "click";
        BTN.Icon = Icon.ArrowJoin;
        BTN.DirectEvents.Click.Event += new ComponentDirectEvent.DirectEventHandler(Click);

        TB = new Toolbar();
        TB.Items.Add(BTN);

        GP.TopBar.Add(TB);

        Store1 = new Store();
        Store1.ID = "Store1";
        Store1.ReadData += new Store.AjaxReadDataEventHandler(WebFormTest_ReadData);

        Model1 = new Model();
        Model1.ID = "Model1";

        Store1.Model.Add(Model1);

        GP.Store.Add(Store1);

        TP = new TreePanel();
        TP.ID = "TP";
        TP.Title = "TP";
        TP.Region = Region.East;
        TP.RootVisible = false;
        TP.Root.Add(new Node() { NodeID = "test", Text = "test" });

        Store2 = new TreeStore();
        Store2.ID = "Store2";
        Store2.ReadData += new TreeStoreBase.ReadDataEventHandler(Store2_ReadData);

        TP.Store.Add(Store2);

        VP.Items.Add(FP);

        //VP.Items.Add(GP);

        VP.Items.Add(TP);

        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            CB.Value = "2";
            TF.Value = "TEXT";
        }
        base.OnInitComplete(e);
    }

    FormPanel FP;
    TextField TF;
    ComboBox CB;
    GridPanel GP;
    Button BTN;
    Toolbar TB;
    Store Store1;
    Model Model1;
    TreePanel TP;
    TreeStore Store2;
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {


        base.CreateChildControls();
    }


    void Store2_ReadData(object sender, NodeLoadEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        //{
        //    this.Store1.DataSource = this.Data;
        //    this.Store1.DataBind();

        //}

    }



    protected void Refresh(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    bool flag = false;
    protected void Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        GP.GetStore().Reload();
        flag = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            TF.Value = "asdasd";
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    protected void WebFormTest_ReadData(object sender, StoreReadDataEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private object[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            return new object[]
        {
            new object[] { "3m Co", 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, "9/1 12:00am" },
        };
        }
    }
}
```

you also can discuss in [Ext.net Forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?24507-Some-trouble-with-ComboBox)

Comment: Thank you for the report. We are working on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We committed the change to the SVN trunk. It will go to the next release (v2.3).

The change is similar to your one, but we decided not to change RawValue as well. Thank you for the report and suggested fix.

**Fix (ComboBoxBase LoadPostData)**

```
protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
{
    this.HasLoadPostData = true;

    string text = postCollection[this.UniqueName];
    string state = postCollection[this.ValueHiddenName.IsNotEmpty() ? this.ValueHiddenName : ("_" + this.UniqueName + "_state")];

    if (state == null && text == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    this.SuspendScripting();
    this.RawValue = text;
    this.Value = text;
    this.ResumeScripting();
```